# Как найти слово в input? Как вывести компонент по клику?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Ситуация такая:

Есть поле ввода, в которое пользователь вводит предложение в таком формате:
"меня зовут* паша, хочу купить* машину".

Задача состоит в том, чтобы найти слова заканчивающиеся на *, после того как пользователь нажал кнопку "Обучить", передать их на сервер, после чего сервер вернет список синонимов этого слова. Затем нужно сгенерировать таблицу со словом в заголовке и словами от сервера под ним. Количество столбцов в таблице должно быть равно количеству слов со звездочкой в предложении.

Я прошу помочь с упрощенной реализацией этой задачи. Нужно реализовать поиск слова со звездочкой в input. Базу слов которые нужно вывести прописать в компоненте. Те без обращения к серверу и сгенерировать таблицу с этими словами.

Вот код компонента который я имею на данный момент:

```
class Content extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // initial state
    this.state = {
      textInput: ""
    };
  }

  clear = () => {
    // return the state to initial
    this.setState({
      textInput: ""
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Paper style={{ maxWidth: 936, marginLeft: "250px", overflow: "hidden" }}>
        <AppBar position="static" color="default" elevation={0}>
          <Toolbar>
            <Grid container spacing={16} alignItems="center">
              <Grid item xs>
                <TextField
                  fullWidth
                  placeholder="Введите фразу которую нужно обучить"
                  id="textInput"
                  InputProps={{
                    disableUnderline: true
                  }}
                  value={this.state.textInput}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  style={{
                    background:
                      "linear-gradient(45deg, #00ACD3 30%, #00BE68 90%)"
                  }}
                >
                  Обучить
                </Button>
                <Tooltip title="Сбросить">
                  <IconButton>
                    <RefreshIcon
                      color="inherit"
                      style={{ display: "block" }}
                      id="clearButton"
                      onClick={this.clear}
                    />
                  </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <div style={{ margin: "40px 16px" }}>
          <Typography color="textSecondary" align="center">
            Пока ничего не было обучено
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Получить массив слов со звездочкой. Разделяем предложение по пробелу или запятой, потом фильтруем по наличию звёздочки в конце

```
let asteriskWords = this.state.textInput.split("/[\s,]/").filter((item) => {
    return item.match("/.*\*$/") > -1;
});
```